# Как получить текст объекта Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Хочу получить текст из элемента с помощью Selenium.
Код:

```
bal = driver.find_element_by_class_name('cabinet__user__grm')
print(bal.get_attribute('text'))
```

[image: Код страницы]

В итоге он выдает "None" хотя текст - 9 000.86 GRM

Comment: Атрибут это то что внутри тега (как в вашем примере `class=...`), а текст элемента достается с помощью `bal.text`.